# Logging in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have created simple test cases using selenium web driver in python. I want to log the execution of the test cases at different levels. How do I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too open-ended as-is. Plausibly you could just `tee` to a file.. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created test case to check the log in of a web application. I want to have a log file which contains the status of execution at every step in the test case. For example, log for steps like opening the browser, getting the url, clicking on an element etc.

Comment: Then you should take a look at [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

I created library in python for logging info messages and screenshots in HTML file called **selenium-logging**
There is also video explanation of package on youtube (25s) called "Python HTML logging"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30244126)